# 2 Identical javascripts don't run with jquery accordian

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ok, here I have a Jquery Accordian with 2 tabs.

1 is for **SELL** and the other one is **BUY**.Each one of them has it's own group of input boxes and javascript attached to them.

Here's for the **BUY** tab

*Input Boxes:-*

```
<tr>
            <td>BUY <input type="text" name="buybtc" id="buybtc" class="validate[required] text-input" placeholder="amount" size="10"> BTC </td>
            <td>At Rate<input type="text" name="rate" id="rate" class="validate[required] text-input" placeholder="rate" size="10">BTC/LTC</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>LTC You will give<input type="text" name="giveltc" readonly id="giveltc" size="10"></td>
            </tr>
```

*Javascript:-*

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function(){
        var buybtc = document.getElementById('buybtc'), //get the amount BTC to be sold 
        giveltc = document.getElementById('giveltc'),
        rate = document.getElementById('rate');

        var constantNumber = 0.022632;

        rate.onkeyup = function () {
        var result = parseFloat(buybtc.value) * parseFloat(rate.value);
        giveltc.value = !isNaN(result) ? result : '';
            };
        }

        //sellbtc = buybtc
        //getltc = giveltc
        </script>
```

**SELL** Tab :-

*Input Boxes*

```
<tr>
  <td>Sell <input type="text" name="sellbtc" id="sellbtc" class="validate[required] text-input" placeholder="amount"> BTC </td>
  <td>At Rate<input type="text" name="rates" id="rates" class="validate[required] text-input" placeholder="rate">LTC/BTC</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>LTC You will get<input type="text" name="getltc" readonly id="getltc"></td>
  </tr>
```

Javascript :-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function(){
        var sellbtc = document.getElementById('sellbtc'), //get the amount BTC to be sold 
        getltc = document.getElementById('getltc'),
        rate = document.getElementById('rate');

        var constantNumber = 0.022632;

        rate.onkeyup = function () {
        var result = parseFloat(sellbtc.value) * parseFloat(rate.value);
        getltc.value = !isNaN(result) ? result : '';
            };
        }
        </script>
```

The work of both these scripts is to calculate the total amount based on the principle amount and rate.The **problem** is, that when I put *only 1 javascript* in the page (for the buy tab)..everything works fine..i.e, the amount is calculated in the third box.But, the moment I place the javascript for the BUY tab..both the javascripts stop working, that means the final amount is not calculated in any of these tabs.

How should I tackled this problem?
Thanks.

---

Updated:-

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function(){
          var sellbtc = document.getElementById('sellbtc'), //get the amount BTC to be sold 
          getltc = document.getElementById('getltc'),
          rate = document.getElementById('rate');

          var constantNumber = 0.022632;

          rate.onkeyup = function () {
            var result = parseFloat(sellbtc.value) * parseFloat(rate.value);
            getltc.value = !isNaN(result) ? result : '';
            };
        }
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function(){
          var buybtc = document.getElementById('buybtc'), //get the amount BTC to be sold 
          giveltc = document.getElementById('giveltc'),
          rateSell = document.getElementById('rateSell');

          var constantNumber = 0.022632;

          rate.onkeyup = function () {
            var resultSell = parseFloat(buybtc.value) * parseFloat(rateSell.value);
            giveltc.value = !isNaN(resultSell) ? resultSell : '';
            };
        }

        //sellbtc = buybtc
        //getltc = giveltc
        </script>

<div id="accordion">
          <h3>Buy</h3>
          <div>
            <p>

            <form action="tradehandler.php?action=buy" method="post" id="formID">
            <table>
            <tr>
            <td>BUY <input type="text" name="buybtc" id="buybtc" class="validate[required] text-input" placeholder="amount" size="10"> BTC </td>
            <td>At Rate<input type="text" name="rateSell" id="rateSell" class="validate[required] text-input" placeholder="rate" size="10">BTC/LTC</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>LTC You will give<input type="text" name="giveltc" readonly id="giveltc" size="10"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
            <td><input type="submit" name="submit"></td>
            </tr>
            </table>
            </form>
            </p>
          </div>
          <h3>Sell</h3>
          <div>
            <p>

            <form action="tradehandler.php?action=sell" method="post" id="formID">
  <table>
  <tr>
  <td>Sell <input type="text" name="sellbtc" id="sellbtc" class="validate[required] text-input" placeholder="amount"> BTC </td>
  <td>At Rate<input type="text" name="rate" id="rate" class="validate[required] text-input" placeholder="rate">LTC/BTC</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>LTC You will get<input type="text" name="getltc" readonly id="getltc"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
  <td><input type="submit" name="submit"></td>
  </tr>
  </table>
  </form>
            </p>
          </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Element `ID`s should be unique per page, you have 2 elements called `rate`, JavaScript will only return the first element. Change them to `sellrate` and `buyrate` (or something)

Comment: @jammykam
I've already tried that before.
Updated the original question.

Answer (score 0):

this work only for sell div

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
            window.onload = function(){
            setAccordion('sellbtc','getltc','rates');
                };
            }
    function setAccordion(btc,ltc,rate)
    {
    var sellbtc = document.getElementById(btc), //get the amount BTC to be sold 
            getltc = document.getElementById(ltc),
            rateVar = document.getElementById(rate);

            var constantNumber = 0.022632;

            rateVar.onkeyup = function () {
            var result = parseFloat(sellbtc.value) * parseFloat(rate.value);
            getltc.value = !isNaN(result) ? result : '';
    }
            </script>
```

if they are on the same page, **you have to change the ID of rates and ltc in the SELL div
and change the script like this:**

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
            window.onload = function(){
            setAccordion('buybtc','getltc','rates');
setAccordion('sellbtc','SELLgetltc','SELLrates');
                };
            }
    function setAccordion(btc,ltc,rate)
    {
    var sellbtc = document.getElementById(btc), //get the amount BTC to be sold 
            getltc = document.getElementById(ltc),
            rateVar = document.getElementById(rate);

            var constantNumber = 0.022632;

            rateVar.onkeyup = function () {
            var result = parseFloat(sellbtc.value) * parseFloat(rate.value);
            getltc.value = !isNaN(result) ? result : '';
    }
            </script>
```

Comment: Updated the question.Could you please check again?
Thanks.

Comment: you have to change also this line rate.onkeyup = function () to rateSell.onkeyup = function ()